# How do I repair grub2 (not) booting 32-bit EFI on a 64-bit machine?

Tags: grub2, boot-loader, uefi, 32bit

I have an Asus EeeBook X205TA which proves very difficult to install Linux on due to obscure new hardware and 32-bit EFI on 64-bit hardware.  I have seen and read a lot of material and I am almost finished.  The problem I have now is as follows:

When I boot the system I always get the `grub>` prompt where I can enter what is written in `/boot/grub/grub.conf` which will work:

```
insmod gzio
insmod part_gpt
insmod btrfs
linux  (hd0,gpt5)/@/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic.efi.signed root=LABEL=UNIXROOT rootflags=subvol=@
initrd (hd0,gpt5)/@/boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-18-generic
```

How do I fix the problem that grub (2.02~beta2) apparently does not find `/boot` in the subvol `@` of the btrfs partition `LABEL=UNIXROOT`?  I have played with `efiboot`, which has 2 relevant entries now, `ubuntu` and `Linux`, one of which gets me to `grub>`, the other to `grub rescue>`.  **How can I get information from grub2 why it fails?**  `grub-update` does not change a thing.

The problem is that I do not know how booting works with EFI ->?-> GRUB ->?-> FS->/boot/grub/grub.cfg, so all my efforts are blind.

What do you need to know?  Ubutu 15.04 64-bit, 32-bit UEFI, 32GB eMMC, Z3735 baytrail CPU, Win 8.1 still alive, Secure Boot disabled, Legacy Boot not a BIOS option, what else?

Comment: I'd rather not start with complicating every bit I can -- that is, wouldn't stick btrfs (or lvm, or whatever) under /boot at the very least on an EeePC... have you read http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html already?

Comment: Dear Michael, You are probably right. I knew that btrfs has advantages over ext4 for SSDs, and I wanted to enable compression because of the small disk (7GB Linux partition including home!).  What I did not know was how badly the Ubuntu installaller can handle btrfs - it has created subvolumes without asking me, and is has no option to enable compression.  openSUSE's installer is much better in this respect.

Comment: I have shrunk the `btrfs` and created a separate `ext4` `boot` partition.  It has not helped.

Comment: Well then Rod's books on EFI are the way to go -- sorry but I've dropped 64-on-32fw experiments last year due to availability of optional 64-bit firmware for my device so no experience-based hints came my way so far...

Answer (score 2):

I've been working with a similar issue all day. I just installed lubuntu on a Quantum Byte QS-1043-QB. It uses the same processor and chipset you are working with. I got the to same point you are.

Basically, you need to install a 32 bit EFI file for grub and 32 bit grub version.

First, install 32-bit support for grub

```
sudo apt-get install grub-efi-ia32 grub-efi-ia32-bin
```

By default, grub is installing a 64 bit EFI, which will not work with the UEFI system on our PCs. I compiled as 32 bit grub EFI on my laptop, then copied it over to the Quantum Byte. I uploaded that EFI file here: [grubia32.efi](http://www.thinktwisted.com/gradschool/Public/grubia32.efi)

I then copied that EFI file over the default grub 64 bit version (do as root):

```
mkdir /boot/efi/EFI
mkdir /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu
cp grubia32.efi /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
```

Update the grub configuration (again, do as root):

```
update-grub
update-grub2
```

At this point, you can reboot and see if it works. You may get lucky. I rebooted, then got dumped to the grub command line. I entered this to tell grub where the config file is:

```
configfile (hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

And the system entered the grub boot menu, but it was all gibberish. After starting up, I updated the grub config file to enable the text based menu and then reinstalled grub to fix the configfile location issue:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Uncomment: GRUB_TERMINAL="console"
Type Ctl-X and hit Y to save.

Reinstall grub:

```
sudo grub-install
```

I rebooted and now everything seems swell! Hope it works for you, good luck.

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  This is indeed useful information for the installation of Linux on Baytrail-based computers.  However, it does not quite answer the question I had (which I have since solved, I will enter the reply here for others when I have the time).

Comment: Ned64, you are right, I did not address your original question, apologies.

Comment: Also, I just installed linux mint on this same machine. The process was much easier. After the initial install, I simply ran the commands to install grub 32 bit, updated grub, and did the reinstall. Machine seems to work no problem. Maybe the original was over complicated.

Comment: @Ned64 please share your knowledge