# Can Kali installed from Kali 64-bit iso run on 32-bit platform?

Tags: boot, kali-linux, 64bit, 32bit

So let's say I download the 64-bit version (`amd64`) iso from official download page, then I boot at a 64-bit pc and start the installation to my 128GB USB.

Let's say we all got both `32-bit` and `64-bit` pc running on UEFI mode, can my USB disk (installed on `64-bit` platform with `amd64` iso) run on my 32-bit pc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not possible. You will probably get the following error message(or some message that is similar to this one):

[image]

If you have 32bit machines, it is safer to download a 32bit OS to boot on both architecture options.

Note also that when talking about EFI, there are some machines that have 32bit EFI, but run amd64 processor so, there are some tweaks that need to be made to make this kind of "boot freak machines" work. Take a look at the related stuff section of this answer.

There is also [this question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/749306/494660) where you can find interesting stuff about dual booting Ubuntu 32-bit EFI and 64-bit EFI. Since Kali Linux is based on Debian, some of the tips could apply to your scenario. As said in the comments, this setup should be possible if using a 32-bit EFI to chainload both kernels, and isolating the `/` on 2 different partitions, making 2 different installations on the same disk.

It should be possible to share `swap` partitions although you could break your system if you "suspend to disk" and then boot on another of your Linux installs. The same way you could share your `/home` partition but you could break software that use files that are architecture dependent like [`rrd`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rrdtool) database files, getting the `ERROR: This RRD was created on another architecture` error.

**Related Stuff:**

- [Installing Windows x64 on 32-bit UEFI (EFI-IA32) via GRUB [duplicate]](https://superuser.com/q/1055305/210242)
- [How do I repair grub2 (not) booting 32-bit EFI on a 64-bit machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/206274/34720)
- [Arch Linux Wiki: Booting 64-bit kernel on 32-bit UEFI](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Booting_64-bit_kernel_on_32-bit_UEFI)

**My opinion:** If you really want an OS that will be able to boot on `i686` and `amd64` i suggest you to use an `i686` Linux distribution.

Comment: Then is it possible to have two kernel and grub to boot on 32 and 64 while other data using the same destination (install both grub in different partition with different bootloader id but using the same `/` partition)?

Comment: Using the same `/` partition i think no, cause  you will "blend" 32bit and 64bit software on the same partition. But i think that if you use a 32bit EFI loader to both Linuxes, and keep them on separated `/` partitions you could even share their `/home` directories on this kind of setup... I never did this setup, but these are my 2 cents on this matter :) Basically, they will share the bootloader, will not share the `/` partition, and COULD share the `/home`

Comment: Then is it possible to have 2 kali (5 partition, 2 `/`, 2 `/boot`, 1 `swap`) on my 128GB USB to run both on 32 bit and 64 bit?

Comment: Should be possible with this layout. Will not be possible if just following your question like "booting with no kernel changes on `amd64`" or sharing the same `/`

Comment: @municial That won't work, since the amd64 kernel will be expecting amd64 libraries and binaries, which the x86 can't work with, and I'm not confident in Kali's ability to set up proper  multiarch support.

Comment: So it's possible to share `swap` partition between `32-bit` and `64-bit` correct?

Comment: @Shadur have you tried? Why would Kali not be able to support multi-arch properly? You don’t even need multi-arch to run 32-bit userspace with a 64-bit kernel...

Comment: In my opinion, this tech stuff is great but it will be a loss of time seting up this kind of environment where you could just use 32bit if that is the point of having a distribution installed that will be most compatible with all your machines. @Munucial, swap setup will be just fine. Both distributions will be able to share it(you may face problems if using "suspend to disk" on one distribution and try to boot the other).

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you can share swap (and data storage partitions, not really `/etc` etc!) just don't hibernate either OS, and the i686-pae version of *ubuntu* used to work with with either 32 or 64bit systems (though this may have been through installing the i686 kernel :D )!

Comment: Yes, and that's why i suggested to use a i686 distro. Most of them have PAE enabled by default(Ubuntu since 12.04 - https://askubuntu.com/q/117744/494660)  :D - Not only `/etc/` but `/var` and `/usr` would be a mess to share between systems. That's why I suggested to keep the entire `/`on separated partitions.